# Oracle SQL PERCENT_RANK Summed Data Within Multiple Groupings

Tags: sql, oracle11g, window-functions

I'm trying to show Percentile ranks based on different groupings.. I originally tried code similar to what I have below.

The problem that I did not realize is that 'over partition' does not ignore the grouping I have. Since I couldn't find a way around this ... I ended up using CTEs to group the data into the percentile rankings I wanted and then using sub queries (10+) for every percentile group I needed.

Is there are more efficient way to do what I intended below?

```
SELECT 
,employee
,dept
,location
,shift
,fq
,fm
,day
,sum(calls)
,sum(handletime)

/*YTD P RANKS */ 

,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept order by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept, location by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept, shift by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_SHIFT

/*QTD P RANKS */ 

,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept order by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept, location by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept, shift by DECODE(sum(calls),0,0,sum(handletime) / sum(calls)) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_SHIFT


from table1

group by 

,employee
,dept
,location
,shift
,fq
,fm
,day
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"The problem that I did not realize is that 'over partition' does not ignore the grouping I have"* - Do you mean that you didn't realize that window functions (and their `PARTITION BY` clauses) are evaluated on the results of the `GROUP BY` clause? Also, is a different result format OK with you, e.g. where different percent ranks are placed in different rows rather than all in one row?

Comment: Yep.. I'd never really used PARTITION BY before and I initially thought it was independent of the select grouping.

 I'm somewhat new to Oracle SQL/PL.. I'll be honest say I usually just tinker with things until they do what I need them to do... This one has me stumped though. 

The idea of having the results in their own rows seems like a better method to me actually. I'd love any help you have to offer. I just checked.. and it's taking me 163 lines to do it at the moment. (15 CTEs, 12 subquerys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited) I'm thinking you might get this to work if you split your query in 3 steps:

1. Calculate the sums first.
2. Calculate the percentage ranks.
3. Apply your final `group by`.

Hopefully, this gets you closer to what you are trying to do.

```
WITH SumView AS (
  SELECT t.*
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by dept) AS sum_call_by_dept
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by dept) AS sum_ht_by_dept
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by dept, location) AS sum_call_by_dept_loc
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by dept, location) AS sum_ht_by_dept_loc
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by dept, shift) AS sum_call_by_dept_shift
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by dept, shift) AS sum_ht_by_dept_shift
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by fq, dept) AS sum_call_by_fq_dept
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by fq, dept) AS sum_ht_by_fq_dept
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by fq, dept, location) AS sum_call_by_fq_dept_loc
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by fq, dept, location) AS sum_ht_by_fq_dept_loc
         ,sum(calls) over (partition by fq, dept, shift) AS sum_call_by_fq_dept_shift
         ,sum(handletime) over (partition by fq, dept, shift) AS sum_ht_by_fq_dept_shift
    FROM table1 t
),  PercentRankView AS (
  SELECT t.*
         /*YTD P RANKS */ 

         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept order by DECODE(sum_call_by_dept,0,0,sum_ht_by_dept / sum_call_by_dept) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept, location by DECODE(sum_call_by_dept_loc,0,0,sum_ht_by_dept_loc / sum_call_by_dept_loc) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by dept, shift by DECODE(sum_call_by_dept_shift,0,0,sum_ht_by_dept_shift / sum_call_by_dept_shift) DESC) as YTD_P_RANK_SHIFT

         /*QTD P RANKS */ 

         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept order by DECODE(sum_call_by_fq_dept,0,0,sum_ht_by_fq_dept / sum_call_by_fq_dept) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept, location by DECODE(sum_call_by_fq_dept_loc,0,0,sum_ht_by_fq_dept_loc / sum_call_by_fq_dept_loc) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
         ,PERCENT_RANK() over (partition by fq, dept, shift by DECODE(sum_call_by_fq_dept_shift,0,0,sum_ht_by_fq_dept_shift / sum_call_by_fq_dept_shift) DESC) as QTD_P_RANK_SHIFT
    FROM SumView t
)
SELECT employee
       ,dept
       ,location
       ,shift
       ,fq
       ,fm
       ,day
       ,sum(calls)
       ,sum(handletime)
       ,YTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
       ,YTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
       ,YTD_P_RANK_SHIFT
       ,QTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
       ,QTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
       ,QTD_P_RANK_SHIFT
  FROM PercentRankView
 GROUP BY employee
          ,dept
          ,location
          ,shift
          ,fq
          ,fm
          ,day
          ,YTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
          ,YTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
          ,YTD_P_RANK_SHIFT
          ,QTD_P_RANK_ALL_LOCATIONS
          ,QTD_P_RANK_LOCAL_LOCATION
          ,QTD_P_RANK_SHIFT
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought that suggestion was going to work out perfectly but I think it runs into the summed data issue. I'm getting 'not a single grouped function'. Since you can't sum within the table1 select. The data needs to be summed by group before the percentiles can be measured.

Comment: my bad. I focused my attention on the `percent_rank()` and didn't notice the `sum`s in the `order by` clause of the analytic function.  I've edited my answer.  I can't say I'm confident about it, as I'm not even sure I completely understand your query's intent.  But hopefully it gets you closer to a working solution that you'll feel comfortable with. Good luck.

Comment: This helps, thanks! I was using CTEs for each different summed grouping I needed. I didn't think about how I could use the window functions to do it all within one CTE.. a big improvement.. thanks again. Sadly it says I don't have enough "rep" to up vote your answer